# Sending data to Jmeter with Websocket

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can anyone with experience with Jmeter tell how to send data to Application after successfully creation of web socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and the easiest way is using [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/wiki/User-manual)

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article for detailed information on using the WebSocket Sampler and alternative options of implementing WebSocket testing using JMeter.

Comment: I have used this but dont know how to send data to Application using webSocket Sampler . I have created connection successfully using webSocket Sampler

Comment: Hi Omer/Dmitri, I am working on websocket sampler and facing the same issue with SEND data. Did you overcome the issue Omer Malik ?
The payload which is being used in my case is in the below format

"SEND\ndestination:/app/event.audience\ncontent-length:382\n\n{\n  \"type\": \"HELLO\",\n  \"message\": \"${token}\",\n  \"params\": null\n}\u0000"


Unable to frame the above payload in the correct format in beanshell pre-processor element.